# Create a bootable image on a Mac OSX to install Ubuntu on a Windows machine

Tags: 12.04, windows, live-usb, macosx, usb-creator

Title says it all - as you can imagine, searching for the answer I have here is utterly impossible to find anything online...I tried this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/installation-guide/amd64/boot-usb-files.html

but that didn't work. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all you could give a step-by-step protocol of what you do and what the result is. "It didn't work" makes it kinda hard to find the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unetbootin` to create bootable usb in mac.